# Prevent table from stretching whole Blazor page horizontally

Tags: css, flexbox, blazor, scrollbar, overflow

I've created a Blazor WebAssembly solution and I'm building it from the sample Blazor app. I have to work with a table that needs to overflow horizontally (it has too many columns). The overflowing table unfortunatelly stretches the `table-container` div, and the whole `page`, and adds a horizontal scrollbar on the whole page.

[image: example of the problem]

What I would like to happen is to add a horizontal scrollbar only to the div containing the table (`table-container` in the example below), presumably `overflow-x: auto;`. A horizontal scrollbar should not appear on the whole page. Additionally, I do not want the table to stretch its container, or any other elements.

One solution that I've seen work is to set the `page` element to `display-block`, and not `display-flex`, as flex behavior seems to cause this issue. I would then need to rearrange all other elements - so I would like to avoid this if possible. Setting the width of the `table-container` using `vw` also solves the issue, but I'm not sure if it would be responsive enough on all screens.

Are there any other solutions to this, apart from fixing the width of the div using `vw`, or changing the whole app to `display-block`?

In order to recreate this scenario, do the following:

- Create the sample Blazor WebAssembly hosted app
- Create a page using one of the following samples

**Simple Paragraphs Sample**

I've added the 2000px width to simulate overflowing.

```
    @page "/test"
    
    <div id="should-contain-scrollbar" class="mt-2" style=" overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
        <div style="width: 2000px;">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Egestas sed sed risus pretium.
            </p>
    
            <p>
                Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis.
            </p>
    
            <p>
                Auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. Id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum. Quam id leo in vitae turpis. Parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna.
            </p>
    
            <p>
                Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus. Nullam eget felis eget nunc. Varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque. Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales.
            </p>
    
            <p>
                Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Simple Table Sample**

```
    @page "/test-table"
    
     <div id="table-container" class="mt-2" style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>One</td>
                    <td>Two</td>
                    <td>Three</td>
                    <td>Four</td>
                    <td>Five</td>
                    <td>Six</td>
                    <td>Seven</td>
                    <td>Eight</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Egestas sed sed risus pretium.
                    </td>
                    <td>Two</td>
                    <td>Three</td>
                    <td>Four</td>
                    <td>
                        03cc6a8e-951b-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        083e7c1a-951b-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        499b9247-69de-4bd6-8650-d18b31e3d33f
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        098e82e3-0bbf-4f00-804e-caf401d06e14
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Egestas sed sed risus pretium.
                    </td>
                    <td>Two</td>
                    <td>Three</td>
                    <td>Four</td>
                    <td>
                        03cc6a8e-951b-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        083e7c1a-951b-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        499b9247-69de-4bd6-8650-d18b31e3d33f
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        098e82e3-0bbf-4f00-804e-caf401d06e14
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: CSS issues should not be listed as Blazor questions.  What you said was correct: you need to use overflow-x to auto.  You might also want to pin your main page dimensions to 100vw or 100%, and make its overflow hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 0; min-width: 100%;` to the `#should-contain-scrollbar` and `#table-container` divs.